# Let $z$ be a complex number, and let $n$ be a positive integer such that $z^n = (z + 1)^n = 1$. Prove that $n$ is divisible by 6.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $z$ be a complex number, and let $n$ be a positive integer such that $z^n = (z + 1)^n = 1$. Prove that $n$ is divisible by 6.

---

I feel like $|z|=1,$ but I don't know how to prove it.  Even if I found that, how would it help?  Solutions are greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

*I believe there's multiple ways to solve this question.  And I would like to solve it using the one without much calculus.  I only know up to intermediate algebra.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee wow, I have to wonder how you find duplicates like that sometimes.

Comment: @SimpleArt, I was one of those who posted the answers:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $|z|^n = |z^n| = 1$, $|z| = 1$.  Similarly, $|z+1| = 1$.  Consider the circles of radius $1$ centred at $0$ and $-1$.  Where do they intersect?

Comment: This looks pretty in my head.  :D

Comment: Nice geometric hint!  Geometry is my favorite math topic. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Clearly $|z|=1$ since $z^n=1$.

Likewise, $|z+1|=1$.

Combining these, we get $z=-\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2$, and with some basic inspection, it follows that these are sixth roots of unity where $(z+1)^3\ne1$ and $(z+1)^2\ne1$, so for $z^n=1$ to be true, $n$ must be a multiple of $6$.

Comment: Please don't copy other people's answers.

Comment: ^ WTF @Tdonut?, this answer was posted before the other one

Comment: @Tdonut I didn't copy anyone's answer >.> Not to mention, short time spans between similar answers are fine IMO.

Comment: Oh well, I need to sleep, but I think these downvotes are fairly unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Taking norm for both equations lead to: $|z| = |z+1| = 1$. Let $z = x+iy\implies x^2+y^2 = 1 = (x+1)^2+y^2\implies 2x+1 = 0 \implies x = -\dfrac{1}{2}, y = \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\implies z = e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}, z+1 = e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}\implies \cos(\dfrac{2\pi n}{3})+i\sin(\dfrac{2\pi n}{3}) = 1 = \cos(\dfrac{\pi n}{3})+i\sin(\dfrac{\pi n}{3})\implies \cos(\dfrac{\pi n}{3}) = 0\implies \dfrac{\pi n}{3} = 2\pi k\implies  n = 6k\implies 6 \mid n$

Comment: Shouldn't it be : $\cos(\dfrac{2\pi n}{3})+i\sin(\dfrac{2\pi n}{3}) + 1 $$= \cos(\dfrac{\pi n}{3})+i\sin(\dfrac{\pi n}{3})?$ Request some elaboration to explain why $\cos(\dfrac{\pi n}{3})=0$